# How do Naishtika Brahmacharis and Smartha Sanyasis repay the Deva and Pitru debts(ऋण)?

Tags: sanyasi, brahmacharya

[**Taittriya Samhita 6.3.10.5**](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/yv/yv06.htm)

> जायमानो वै ब्राह्मणस्त्रिभिर् ऋणवा जायते  ब्रह्मचर्येण ऋषिभ्यो यज्ञेन
>   देवभ्यः
>
> प्रजया पितृभ्य एष वा अनृणो यः पुत्री यज्वा ब्रह्मचारिवासी

**Rough translation:**

> A Brahmana on birth is born with a threefold debt, first one is to the
>   Rishis (Rishi Rina); second one is to the devatas (Deva Rina); and the
>   third one is to the ancestors (Pitru Rina). He is freed from his first
>   debt who lived as a Brahmachari, **he is freed from the second debt by
>   peforming Yajnas, and the third debt can be fulfilled by begetting a
>   son.**

Now, in order to repay the second and third debts, one has to marry as without wife no one is allowed to perform sacrifices and without wife one cannot beget a son. As Naishtika Brahmacharis and Smartha Sanyasis never marry, how do they repay the second debt and third debt?

Comment: The Qs https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/8929/12304 and https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/16785/12304 are strongly related or may be possible duplicate...

Answer (score 7):

In [Śrīmad-Bhāgavatam (Bhāgavata Purāṇa) 11.5.41](https://vedabase.io/en/library/sb/11/5/41/), 
Devarṣi Nārada narrated a conversation between king Nimi and nava-yogendras (sons of Ṛṣabhadeva) to king Vasudeva (Lord Krishna's father):

> देवर्षिभूताप्तनृणां पितॄणां न किङ्करो नायमृणी च राजन्
>
> सर्वात्मना यः शरणं शरण्यं गतो मुकुन्दं परिहृत्य कर्तम् ॥ ११.५.४१ ॥
>
> O King, one who has given up all material duties and has taken full shelter of the lotus feet of Mukunda, who offers shelter to all, **is not indebted to the demigods [Devas], great sages [Rishis], ordinary living beings, relatives, friends, mankind or even [Pitrus]** one’s forefathers who have passed away. Since all such classes of living entities are part and parcel of the Supreme Lord, one who has surrendered to the Lord’s service has no need to serve such persons separately.

As you can see in above verse, by full shelter of the Lord's feet also one gets freed from these debts.

---

**Related**

[Will Brahmacharis (life long bachelors) get moksha?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/8929/will-brahmacharis-life-long-bachelors-get-moksha)

[Which scripture says that a sannyāsi can liberate 21 generations of ancestors without performing the śrāddha?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/16785/which-scripture-says-that-a-sanny%C4%81si-can-liberate-21-generations-of-ancestors-wi)