# Are there any other ways to get rid of Pitri-Rina?

Tags: pitru, heaven

Getting rid of [Pitri Rina is done by having a son.](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/18580/23709)
Are there any other ways to get [rid of Pitri-Rina ?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/16791/23709)